# android не работает POST запрос

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

у меня есть класс webRequest для Async запросов

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

    public class webRequest {
        public final int _GET=1;
        public final int _POST=2;

        webRequest(){}

    String makeRequest(String urladdress, String requestmethod, HashMap<String,String> params){
        URL url;
        StringBuilder fullUrl=new StringBuilder();
        String response="";
        int reqresponsecode=0;
        try{
            fullUrl.append(urladdress);
            if(params!=null){
                fullUrl.append("?");
                StringBuilder requestresult=new StringBuilder();
                boolean first = true;
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
                    if (first) {
                        first = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        requestresult.append("&");
                    }
                    requestresult.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                    requestresult.append("=");
                    requestresult.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
                }
                fullUrl.append(requestresult);
            }
            url=new URL(fullUrl.toString());
            HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setUseCaches(true);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod(requestmethod);

            reqresponsecode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if(reqresponsecode== HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
                    response+=line;
            }
            else response="no response-1. code: "+reqresponsecode;
        }
        catch(Exception e){response=e.toString();}
        return response.equals("")?"no response-2":response;
    }


}
```

но он не отправляет POST запросы. в чем проблема?